# How to define a string variable to be JSON valid - Android

Tags: android, json

I have this parse class. this line exactly what causes the "Unable to parse" toast to appear and the app to crush:`JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);` because data String variable isn't initialised. I do not know how to initialise it properly as I do not understand JSON concept deep enough.

The whole class code:

```
public class Parser extends AsyncTask <Void, Void,Integer> {

    Context ctx;
    ListView listView;
    String data;
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();


    public Parser(Context ctx, String data, ListView listView) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.data=data;
        this.listView = listView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return this.parse();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);

        if (integer == 1) {

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Unable to Parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private int parse() {
        Log.d("Joudi",data);
        try {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject jo = null;

            titles.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = jo.getString("post_title");
                titles.add(title);
            }
            return 1;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;

    }
}
```

What I need to know is how to initialise "data" properly and if you suggest any excellent specific source (I know there are too many and this is the problem) to learn JSON I'd appreciate it.

The code of calling the parser from another class:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        //Reset listView
        listView.setAdapter(null);

        if ( s!= null ){

            if(! s.contains("null")) {

                Parser parser = new Parser(ctx,s,listView);
                parser.execute();


            }else {
                noNetwork.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                noData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        }else {
            noNetwork.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            noData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }
```

Log:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value already of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
    at com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange.Parser.parse(Parser.java:55)
    at com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange.Parser.doInBackground(Parser.java:37)
    at com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange.Parser.doInBackground(Parser.java:16)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Post the code of how you call this Parser class.

Comment: check now please.

Comment: Put a Log at `s` and post the value.

Comment: I still do not know how to make a Log at something...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: Can you share the logs `JSONException` logs you are getting?

Comment: check now please.

Comment: The string that you logged with tag `Joudi` seems not to be visible in the logs...

Comment: Your string appears to be blank?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good intro to JSON:  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Your code in parse() assumes a JSON array with object(s) inside that have the name "post_title" and a string value.  If you initialize data to the following, it should work:

```
data = "[{\"post_title\":\"title1\"},{\"post_title\":\"title2\"}]";
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand, I mentioned that data isn't initialised and doesn't have contents.

Comment: Oh, well, if at this point in the code: `JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);` data is not initialized, then that's what will throw a JSONException.  In this line, data must be a valid JSON string.

Comment: You can try initializing it like this as the very first thing you do in parse():  `data = "{[ \"Fiesta\", \"Focus\", \"Mustang\" ]}";`

Comment: I used this statement exactly but I 'll retry it again. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: I added the initialising statement in the parse method is that right?

Comment: yes, it should be the very first statement in the parse() method

Comment: I've got this error: json.JSONException: Value already of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: I updated my answer above and just tried it myself in Android Studio and it works.  Can you try the code in the answer?

Comment: oh now it displayed title 1 and 2 in the  list!! but it should instead search in the database...

Comment: What's happening is that wherever the data is coming from, it's not a valid JSON array, which is what your parse() method is expecting.  You need to print out the result you're getting from the database and see what it is exactly and then parse it correctly.

Comment: But now you know what a JSON array looks like and you know that your code works for a valid array.  You can accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138441/discussion-between-user233531-and-awardak).